# Filtering ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I can't make a simple query working although I follow the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups.

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False)    
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

I registered an user, whose name is "a" and a course, which is called "mathématique" but I got this in the shell :

```
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: a>]

>>> User.objects.filter(courses__name__contains='mathématique')
[]

>>> User.objects.filter(courses__name__in='mathématique')
[]
```

It always return an empty list and I can't understand why. When I see the administration I can see a `User` who has a "mathématique" course.

EDIT

forms.py

```
from user.models import User, Course

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cours_choices = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('cours_choices', 'faculty', 'description')
```

EDIT2

Okay, the problem is solved. The above queries works fine. I don't know why it's working now but I suspect the culprit could be a confusion about the name "cours", which was used for the class and the field

Comment: what happens when you do `User.objects.filter(cours__cours='mathématique')` ?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with encoding. Try a simpler course name.

Comment: I still have an empty list :
>>> User.objects.filter(cours__cours='mathématique')
[]

Comment: I added a cours, called "apple" but I still have the empty list :>>> Offer.objects.filter(cours__cours='apple')
[]

Comment: Are you using MySQL database? It might be an issue with the default charset and collation you are using. 

Also, can you check with `User.objects.filter(course__name__contains='math')?`

Comment: try: `User.objects.all()[0].course`

Comment: @AtishayJain: No I use Sqlite

it seems to work! it gives me : <django.db.models.fields.related.create_many_related_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f4a6da1df98>

But : print(User.objects.all()[0].course) return user.Course.None

Comment: If `User.objects.all()[0].course` returns None, it means that the `User` a(assuming it is the first user in the result) is not currently associated with any course. You can use `add()` to associate a particular `User` with a `Course` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: It explains why the list is empty. But how is it possible? A made a form and the user has to choose his courses, it's required.

Comment: Can we have a look at your Django form? :)

Comment: of course, I put it in an edit

Comment: `User.objects.all()[0].course` returning None means absolutely nothing, because it will always return None. Try `User.objects.all()[0].course.all()` instead.

Comment: yes it works', it gives [<Course: apple>] :D
But then, how do I do to make a query allowing me to get all the user who choose the apple course?

Answer (score 1):

What if you remove "course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)" from class User and move it to class Course as follows "course = models.ManyToManyField(User)" and do following query:

User.objects.filter(course__name__contains='mathématique')

---

please note I have changed (Course) to (User)

Comment: After your changes there is no `course` field in User, so it will raise an exception.